# Modelling Loan Payments - Calculate IRR

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape, irr

Working with loan data.
I have a dataframe with the columns:

```
df_irr = df1[['id', 'funded_amnt_t', 'Expect_NoPayments','installment']]
```

ID of the Loan | Funded Amount | Expected Number of Payments | fixed instalment of the annuity.

I have estimated the number of payments with regression analysis.
the loans have 36 or 60 months maturity.

Now I am trying to calculate the expected irr (internal rate of return).

But I am stuck

I was planning to use `numpy.irr`
However, I never had the chance to use it - as my date is not in the right format?

I have tried pandas pivot and reshape functions. No Luck.

Time series of cash flows:
- Columns: Months 0 , ...., 60
- Rows: ID for each loan
- Values in Month 0 = - funded_amount
- Values in Month 0-60: installment if expected_number_of_payments > months

My old Stata code was:

```
keep id installment funded_amnt expectednumberofpayments
sort id
expand 61, generate(expand)
bysort id : gen month = _n      
gen cf = 0
replace cf = installment if (expectednumberofpayments+1)>=month
replace cf = funded_amnt*-1 if month==1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJRLd.jpg)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: :-) Need the code for reshaping / building the dataframe.

Comment: Stuff I tried now: df_irr2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df_irr, index= 'id', columns= 'funded_amnt_t' 'Expect_NoPayments''installment')

df_irr3 = df_irr.groupby(by = df_irr['id'])           df_irrT.pivot(index='id', columns='Expect_NoPayments', values='installment')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`numpy.irr` is the wrong formula to use. That formula is for irregular payments (e.g. $100 in month 1, $0 in month 2, and $400 in month 3). Instead, you want to use `numpy.rate`. I'm making some assumptions about your data for this solution:

```
 import numpy as np
 df_irr['rate'] = np.rate(nper=df_irr['Expect_NoPayments'],
                          pmt=df_irr['installment'],
                          pv=df_irr['funded_amnt_t'])
```

More information can be found here [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.rate.html).

Comment: Nope, not the solution. And I still need to reshape my dataset.

Comment: Why is this not the solution? What do you mean by "reshape your dataset"? If you do the math, `IRR` with even payments and `rate` will give you the same result. Can you please be more specific with your question?

Comment: It might be useful if you added your desired output for the question.

Comment: Dear @Polkaguy6000 I did the best I could to put down an excel file to explaint the desired outcome.

Comment: No i have tried this 
for i in range(0, 60):
    if i == 0:
        df_irrT['i'] = df_irr[['funded_amnt_t']]
    if i <= df_irr[['Expect_NoPayments']]:
        df_irrT['i'] = df_irr[['installment']]